# JSON_TABLE dynamic path expression

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

What is the best practice to select data using `JSON_TABLE` with dynamic path expression? For example first path must be `$.ORDERITEM[*]` and another is `$.OPENORDERS[*]`. Path must be literal, `REPLACE`/`REGEX_REPLACE` truncates `CLOB` to to 32K - doesn't suit me. Both arrays have the same data, there is no problem. I have few ideas: first, is two selects with different paths, using union; second, is sub-functions with different paths.

```
FOR j IN (
    SELECT *
    FROM JSON_TABLE(v_response, '$.ORDERITEM[*]'
            COLUMNS(WERKS       VARCHAR2    PATH '$.WERKS',
                    AUFNR       VARCHAR2    PATH '$.AUFNR',
                    MATNR       VARCHAR2    PATH '$.MATNR'
    ))
) LOOP
    ...
END LOOP;
```

Comment: Since you are already in PL/SQL, you can use dynamic SQL, loop on dynamic cursor, even pipelined function over an OBJECT type (if the columns returned were different it would be one if not the only solution...), but this latest solution require experience with ODCI API (ODCITableDescribe, ODCITablePrepare, ODCITableStart, ODCITableFetch, ODCITableClose...)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, dynamic SQL is nice solution, but in my case is not convenient to fetch data. This time I try REPLACE, to replace the array name, this enough for me. But I can't understand what means "If replace_string is a CLOB or NCLOB, then Oracle truncates replace_string to 32K.". What is 32K? In my test using REPLACE was 157576419 characters, and everything was fine.

Comment: Use a CTE per json object to transform to row then union them - it will be a bit more code but it should be a lot faster to write

Comment: 32K: the max size of a VARCHAR2 in PL/SQL

Comment: If your JSON contains only this type of arrays at the same level, you may use wildcards and filtering to access nested arrays. See https://dbfiddle.uk/dYaCc7co

Comment: @ES. - that 32k truncation in `regexp_replace()` only applies to `replace_string`, not `source_char`. It's unclear what you're applying the function too, but it sounds like your `replace_string` is going to be a short literal like `'OPENORDERS'`, not anything close to that limit.

Comment: To rename the ORDERITEM entry you may give a try to json_transform: json_transform(js, RENAME '$.ORDERITEM' = 'OPENORDERS')

Comment: JSON_TRANSFORM is nice! But it works only in SQL query? v_response := JSON_TRANSFORM(v_response, RENAME '$.ORDERITEM' = 'OPENORDERS' RETURNING CLOB PRETTY); - doesn't work.

Comment: @ES. `select json_transform(...) into v_response from dual`